# how to change size of bitmap in iOS?

Tags: ios, bitmap, core-graphics

I create a bitmap with the size of a view.When the view increase height,How can I increase the height of this bitmap and draw it like this:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
  CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

  CGContextSaveGState(context);

  if (myBitmapContext)
  {
     CGImageRef imageref = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(myBitmapContext);
     CGContextDrawImage(context, rect, imageref);
     CGImageRelease(imageref);
  }

  CGContextRestoreGState(context);
}
```

Thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CGContextScaleCTM` before drawing the image